# Set cookies depending on user in Struts 2

Tags: java, cookies, struts2

I want to set cookies depending on the user who's logged in. So when user x logs in, he can see his name that he has entered, and if user y logs in he sees his name that he also entered earlier. How would I do that? Because right now, the latest user who was logged in is the value of the cookies.

I verify my users like this:

```
public class LoginService {
    public boolean verifyLogin(User user){
        if(user.getUserId().equals("userId") && user.getPassword().equals("password")){
            return true;
        }

        if(user.getUserId().equals("random") && user.getPassword().equals("a")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I set my cookies in my `LoginAction`:

```
public Set<Cookie> getCookies(){
      Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();

      Cookie userId = new Cookie("userId", user.getUserId() );
      userId.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year!
      userId.setPath("/"); //Make it at root.
      cookies.add(userId);}
```

This is how I set my cookies in my `FormAction`:

```
 public Set<Cookie> getCookies(){
      Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();

      Cookie name = new Cookie("name", userInfo.getName() );
      name.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year!
      name.setPath("/"); //Make it at root.
      cookies.add(name); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the cookie for the user that is already verified. If the user is verified first you save it into the session. Then use the session user to provide the cookie. Like this,

```
if (verifyLogin(User user))
  session.put("user", user);
```

To save a cookie first get the user from session

```
public Set<Cookie> getCookies(){
      Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();
      User user = (User) session.get("user");
      if (user != null){
          Cookie userId = new Cookie("userId", user.getUserId() );
          userId.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year!
          userId.setPath("/"); //Make it at root.
          cookies.add(userId);
      }
      return cookies;
}
```

To get access to the session map you can use `SessionAware` interface. Another approach is to get session from the action context.

Note that a cookie is shared by the browser. If you are using the same browser at the same time you entering with different user it will use the same cookie unless you provide per session cookie implementation.